# smtplib.SMTPNotSupportedError: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server

Tags: python-3.7, smtplib

I am a python newbie trying to email using Python 3.7.
I am referring to the following python web page to put together my code.
https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/email.examples.html
I am not able to understand what is wrong. Do I have to update any settings in Outlook for the email to go through? Weird that the above documentation doesn't mention anything about my email password

```
    #!/usr/bin/env python3
    import smtplib
    from email.message import EmailMessage 
    body = "Hello User,\nThis is to notify you that...."
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg.set_content(body)
    msg['Subject'] = 'Name Clash.....'
    msg['From'] = 'pukav@outlook.com'
    msg['To'] = 'iampukav@gmail.com'
    s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp-mail.outlook.com', 587)
    s.login('pukav@outlook.com', 'mypassword')
    s.send_message(msg)
    s.quit()
```

ERRORS:

in login "SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server."

smtplib.SMTPNotSupportedError: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.

Comment: Have you checked if the Outlook account needs to be configurated to accept third party smtp clients ? It's very common with gmail. Never tried with Outlook though. It could be an option like _"Allow insecure applications"_ or something like that.

Comment: So far, I haven't found anything like that in Outlook. I tried using a gmail account as well and enabled the 3rd party option. But I kept getting the error "smtplib.SMTPNotSupportedError: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server."

Answer (score 4):

I had the same error for Gmail server and found the solution below.
(I am not sure this solution will be perfectly shaped for Outlook)

```
import smtplib
from typing import List

SMTP_HOST = "smtp.gmail.com"
SMTP_PORT = 587


def send_email(from_addr: str, to_addr: List[str], subject: str) -> None:
    msg = f"From: {from_addr}\r\nTo: {','.join(to_addr)}\r\nSubject: {subject}\r\n"

    with smtplib.SMTP(host=SMTP_HOST, port=SMTP_PORT) as server:
        server.starttls()
        server.login(SMTP_USER, SMTP_PASSWORD)
        server.sendmail(from_addr, to_addr, msg)
```

**Important note:**
When using Gmail, please remember to turn on [access for less secure apps](https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps)

Comment: This one is it.

Comment: i coud not find it under the link given above. Maybe something changed in google links.

Here is the navigation from your google page:
Security->signing in to google ->  2-Step Verification-> app passwords

Anyways, [here](https://support.google.com/accounts/answer/185833) is the google doc that helped me.

Answer (score 1):

After creating the SMTP connection, you should login: `s.login('email', 'password')`

EDIT:
Here is the code I have used for years. I used this to send email from a G-Suite account:

```
server = smtplib.SMTP_SSL(serverAddress, portNumber)
server.ehlo()
server.login(username, password)
```

Comment: Yes, I tried doing that as well.  "SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.")
smtplib.SMTPNotSupportedError: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.

Comment: Thank you @thedadams. But, I don't think Python 3.7.3 supports SSL

Comment: I said that because, it gave me the following error: AttributeError: module 'smtplib' has no attribute 'SMTP_SSL'

Answer (score 1):

Steps:

1. Try this:

   ```py
   s = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.gmail.com', 587)
   s.starttls()
   s.ehlo()
   s.login(username, password)
   ```
2. If email is ***@gmail.com

   Turn this ON: https://myaccount.google.com/lesssecureapps
   If email is something else (ex. ***@outlook.com), then no need to do step 2

Comment: he did not write s.ehlo answer is to write starttls and ehlo together

Answer (score 0):

This works for me!

```py
import smtplib
    
server_365 = smtplib.SMTP('smtp.office365.com', '587')
    
server_365.ehlo('mylowercasehost')

server_365.starttls()
    
server_365.ehlo('mylowercasehost')
```

Reference: [Office365 smtp server does not respond to ehlo() in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44763856/office365-smtp-server-does-not-respond-to-ehlo-in-python/74546565#74546565)