# smtp errors when trying to send email from python vis office365

Tags: python-3.x, email, smtp, office365, smtplib

```
def send_mail(to, subject, body_text):
    SERVER = "smtp.office365.com"
    FROM = "myemail@mycompany.com"

    # Prepare actual message
    msg = EmailMessage()
    msg.set_content(body_text, subtype='html')
    msg['Subject'] = subject
    msg['From'] = FROM
    msg['To'] = to

    # Send the mail
    server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER, 587)
    server.ehlo()
    server.starttls()
    server.ehlo()
    server.login("myemail@mycompany.com", "password")
    server.send_message(msg)
    server.quit()
```

I have this function for sending emails. This is giving me error -

```
smtplib.SMTPNotSupportedError: STARTTLS extension not supported by server.
```

I tried to follow some of the answers here - [STARTTLS extension not supported by server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6355456/starttls-extension-not-supported-by-server/52278682) and modified my code to remove `server.ehlo()` before `server.starttls()` but that gives this error -

```
smtplib.SMTPHeloError: (501, b'5.5.4 Invalid domain name [SN2PR01CA0061.prod.exchangelabs.com]')
```

Also tried running by removing the line `server.starttls()` which gives this error -

```
smtplib.SMTPNotSupportedError: SMTP AUTH extension not supported by server.
```

The `send_email` function was working fine up until now when I changed my modem from Xfinity standard rented modem to store bought Netgear Nighthawk C7000. My internet service provider is Xfinity. I don't know if this is an issue but felt like I should mention since this is the only thing that has changed since email sending stopped working.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out the issue -

Debugging the issue - Add `server.set_debuglevel(1)` after `server = smtplib.SMTP(SERVER, 587)` to get the response:

```
send: 'ehlo DESKTOP-B47NVUE.hsd1.tx.comcast.net.\r\n'
reply: b'501 5.5.4 Invalid domain name [SN4PR0701CA0045.namprd07.prod.outlook.com]\r\n'
reply: retcode (501); Msg: b'5.5.4 Invalid domain name [SN4PR0701CA0045.namprd07.prod.outlook.com]'
```

In addition to the above response, it also raises this:

```
File "C:\Users\Dhruv Gami\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36\lib\smtplib.py", line 752, in starttls
    "STARTTLS extension not supported by server.")
smtplib.SMTPNotSupportedError: STARTTLS extension not supported by server.
```

Solving -
I used the answer given here - [Office365 smtp server does not respond to ehlo() in python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44763856/office365-smtp-server-does-not-respond-to-ehlo-in-python) to solve it.

Basically use `server.ehlo('mylowercasehost')` in the `send_mail` code at both places.